# Kotlin .split() with multiple regex

Tags: regex, kotlin

```
  Input: """aaaabb\\\\\cc"""
  Pattern: ["""aaa""", """\\""", """\"""]
  Output: [aaa, abb, \\, \\, \, cc]
```

How can I split *Input* to *Output* using patterns in *Pattern* in Kotlin?

I found that Regex("(?<=cha)|(?=cha)") helps patterns to remain after spliting, so I tried to use looping, but some of the patterns like '\' and '[' require escape backslash, so I'm not able to use loop for spliting.

EDIT:

```
  val temp = mutableListOf<String>()
  for (e in Input.split(Regex("(?<=\\)|(?=\\)"))) temp.add(e)
```

This is what I've been doing, but this does not work for multiple regex, and this add extra "" at the end of temp if Input ends with "\"

Comment: When I try to print `"aaabb\\\\\cc"` I get `source.kt:4:23: error: illegal escape: '\c'`. Are you sure the input is correct? Maybe you have `"""aaabb\\\\\cc"""`?

Comment: Yes input is correct. It should be a string.

Comment: When using your code, it does not compile - see [this](https://rextester.com/MZOC2445). Please update with your actual data (*Fork it* at the bottom).

Comment: Oh I see the point. I'm sorry it should be """aaabb\\\\\cc"""

Comment: And what about `"""(.)\1?""".toRegex().findAll(text).map{it.value}.toList()`?

Comment: I added as comment in your answer

Comment: Oh, it is still  unclear. Do you mean that the `Pattern` is a list like `listOf("aaa", """\\""", """\""")` that is used to build a pattern dynamically?

Comment: yes, sorry about the unclear explanation, I'll fix it.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the function I wrote for some previous question that splits by a pattern keeping all matched and non-matched substrings:

```
private fun splitKeepDelims(s: String, rx: Regex, keep_empty: Boolean = true) : MutableList<String> {
    var res = mutableListOf<String>() // Declare the mutable list var
    var start = 0                     // Define var for substring start pos
    rx.findAll(s).forEach {           // Looking for matches     
        val substr_before = s.substring(start, it.range.first()) // // Substring before match start
        if (substr_before.length > 0 || keep_empty) {
            res.add(substr_before)      // Adding substring before match start
        }
        res.add(it.value)               // Adding match          
        start = it.range.last()+1       // Updating start pos of next substring before match
    }
    if ( start != s.length ) res.add(s.substring(start))  // Adding text after last match if any
    return res
}
```

You just need a dynamic pattern from yoyur `Pattern` list items by joining them with a `|`, an *alternation operator* while remembering to escape all the items:

```
val Pattern = listOf("aaa", """\\""", "\\") // Define the list of literal patterns
val rx = Pattern.map{Regex.escape(it)}.joinToString("|").toRegex() // Build a pattern, \Qaaa\E|\Q\\\E|\Q\\E
val text = """aaaabb\\\\\cc"""
println(splitKeepDelims(text, rx, false))
// => [aaa, abb, \\, \\, \, cc]
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/DKE2797)

Note that between `\Q` and `\E`, all chars in the pattern are considered literal chars, not special regex metacharacters.

Comment: if I have pattern like ["aa", "a", "\\\", "\\"],  output should be [aa, a, bb, \\\, \\, cc]

Comment: Great it seems like it's working in example case, but what if I want to split "\\\\\" into "\\\" and "\\"?

Comment: Also even if the input is "aaa", if don't have "aa" and "a" in Pattern, it shouldn't split it.

Comment: @JGee When exactly do you want to "split"? What are the exact rules?

Comment: what I meant as Pattern is the pattern in my question below the Input.

Comment: I edited input, pattern and output little bit from question